# Rscript summary unexpected output

Tags: rscript

I have a part of code

```
data <- read.csv(args[1]);
s <- summary(data$Latency);
cpuIdle <- read.csv(args[2]);
cpuBusy <- sapply(cpuIdle$value, function(x) { 100-x; });
cpuSum <- summary(cpuBusy);
print(cpuSum);
print(s);
```

cpuSum output is OK

```
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   3.00    9.50   15.00   13.18   18.00   18.00
```

but s output seems strange and unexpected for me

```
      1       0       3       2       4       5       6       7       8       9 
1028641  860772  486388  407815  367286  220960  111822   47377   19483   10219 
     10      11      12      13      14      15      31      30      29      28 
   6666    4460    3081    2181    1523    1077     940     918     914     893 
     33      32      27      26      34      16      35      36      25      37 
    888     886     858     786     786     771     700     679     671     621 
     17      24      38      39      23      40      18      41      19      22 
    570     563     490     457     436     428     410     370     326     304 
     21      20      42      43      44      45      46      47      48      50 
    303     286     270     269     214     185     159     133     117     105 
     49      51      52      54      53      55      57      56      81      82 
    103      75      65      54      53      39      38      34      29      28 
    207      86     206      79      78      59      80      64      83      85 
     27      27      26      25      23      22      21      20      18      18 
     60      63      73      84      87     205      58      72      75      76 
     17      17      17      17      17      16      16      16      16      15 
     88      89      91     204     208      61      62      69      94      66 
     15      15      15      14      14      14      14      14      13      12 
     92      67     102      70      77      93      95      65      90 (Other) 
     12      11      10      10      10      10      10       9       9     213
```

head of file for s data:

```
elapsed,label,success,Latency
103,request,true,102
120,request,true,117
104,request,true,102
104,request,true,102
127,request,true,122
3,request,true,1
3,request,true,3
111,request,true,102
4,request,true,3
```

head of file for cpuIdle data:

```
timestamp,value
1684166631,96
1684166642,96
1684166652,96
1684166662,96
1684166672,96
1684166682,97
1684166692,97
```

Rscript --version
R scripting front-end version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)

What can I do to these outputs be equals?

Comment: Can you show the first 10-20 lines of the csv file? That would make it easier to explain the output.

Comment: File for s data is big (about 11MB), I suppose, that it was corrupted in a middle, because I record a new file and it is OK with my code now.

Comment: So do you mean that your problem is solved now? If so it can be closed as 'not reproducible'.

Comment: Yes, problem is solved